# Options to use SQL Server Data Tools 2010 in combination with TFS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I'm currently using SQL Server Data Tools 2010 (combined with a SQL Server 2012). Recently I've begun switching to Visual Studio 2013 in combination with TFS.

Now I don't want to acquire any new licenses or having compatibility issues (from what I saw the Data Tools 2013 have SQL Server 2014 as prereqs but I'm running a SQL Server 2012).

So my question here is:

- Can a project which is created with the SQL Server Data Tools 2010 be used with a 2013 TFS and if so how
- OR if that is not possible: can I use the 2013 tools without having to acquire a SQL Server 2014 (so no additional licenses needed and no compatibility issues with my SQL Server 2012)?

Comment: I don't know where you got that idea of a SQL Server 2014 prereq.... - but SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2013 work **just fine** with SQL Server 2012 ....

Comment: I had installed Vs 2013 (professional) and then downloaded the datatools for 2013 (as I saw nowhere any GUI like I had in the 2010 data tools) and when I tried to install the 2013 datatools (http://www.microsoft.com/de-at/download/details.aspx?id=42313) it wanted to install at least part of the 2014 sql server. Like I indicated I can have overlooked something there (but searches didn't prompt me to any error I made there or wrong assumption)

Comment: There's absolutely **no mention** of SQL Server **2014** as a prereq **anywhere** on that download page ....

Comment: That is what I meant I had been surprised when I tried to install it and it tried to install part of sql server 2014 (thus part of 2014 is included there and that made me sceptical of it working with a 2012 sql server and how it is licencnsing wise. Thus also the idea to stay with the 2010 tools or if that is not possible to see if I can use the others in combination with 2012 sql server without probs).

Comment: So you sayin gthat there should be no issues at all in using the 2013 tools in combination with a 2012 sql server?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2013 has **no** immediate requirement for SQL Server 2014.

As a matter of fact, the versions supported in the data tools goes back all the way to **2005**!

[image]

I just imported an existing SQL Server 2012 database, made some modifications, and re-deployed it back out to SQL Server 2012 - **not a single issue** .....

Comment: @Thomas: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.